# .net ashx Web Handler how to return lists

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, json, web-services

I have a vb.net web handler which builds two strings   The strings basically looks like this:
["filename", "filepath"],["filename", filepath"],...,["filename", filepath"]

I need to return it in a way that the strings are sent with the name of the list, followed by the list
["listname": {["filename", "filepath"],["filename", filepath"],...,["filename", filepath"]}

I know that the web handler will automatically json encode the data, and that the way I have built my list should be reworked (the way we previously used this it was exactly what we needed).

What might be a better way for me to house my data and return it to the browser in a way that is understood correctly?

Comment: the answer in this post might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392413/asp-net-returning-json-with-ashx

Comment: Thank you jfmags, I did take a look at that post previously and I spent some time trying to figure out if that would work, however, web handlers automatically json encode the response, so that would end up double encoding the string.  See this link for more information on that http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/.

The way the post I linked to suggests to handle it is by creating an object.  I admit I am inexperienced with this area.  I'm not sure how best to structure an object to return.

Comment: Do you currently have a handler (.ashx) or a web method? I don't believe that a handler will automatically json encode the response. Post the code for your handler and I'll help you out.

Comment: its a handler .ashx.  When I used the method in your link it did double encode.  But I had other issues as well.  I will post some code after a meeting here.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: jfmags, your first comment was 100% correct.  please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in this post might help you out:
[ASP.NET Returning JSON with ASHX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392413/asp-net-returning-json-with-ashx)

```
context.Response.Write( 
jsonSerializer.Serialize( 
    new 
    { 
        listname = new[] { "filename", "filepath" }... 
    } 
)
```

);

Comment: Thank you for your direction on this.  It is appreciated!