# Aspx file returns json together with page html

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

My jquery ajax code calls same aspx file which returns the expected json formatted string, but followed by the entire html:

```
{"UserMsg":"Data here"}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nb-NO">
<head>
etc ...
```

It's tempting to just accept the behavior and regex out the first line that I need, but I would like to know what is causing this error. Fiddler tells me that mime types involved are:

```
Request: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Response: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

I return the string with Response.Write from Page_Load event in code behind file. It looks just fine there, but somewhere on the way back to my ajax function, the page html is added.

I know this type of problem has been discussed many times before, but I can't find anything describing exact this scenario where the jsonstring actually is returned.

Is it possible to diagnose my problem with this information, or should I post more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you are using a Page to Return JSON. My advise is that you implement an JSON Handler to perform the same action and it looks from my end like the correct approach to get the result you want.

The accepted standard for for these type of handler is [some name].ashx.

You can find some code samples and steps to follow here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/210706/Simple-JSON-handler-for-ASP-NET-to-implement-AJAX

and some other posts regarding this subject here:

[ASP.NET Returning JSON with ASHX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392413/asp-net-returning-json-with-ashx)

Comment: I wasn't even aware of the ashx template type :-} 

Looks promising. I hope it's easier to use than asmx webservices which I think are hard to use with json, and hard to debug as well.